# A Fourier transform exercise

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I´m reading a paper and there is one step that I don´t know how to get there, so, any help will be good.

Let
\begin{equation}
U=\int\limits_0^tu(\tau)d\tau.
\end{equation}

Then, they say that the Fourier transform of $U$ (in relation to time $t$) is given by

$$\hat{U}(w)=\hat{u}(w)/(iw)+\pi\hat{u}(0)\delta(w).$$

When I tried to calculate the Fourier transform of $U$ I couldn´t reproduce that result. My attempt:

$$\hat{U}(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-itw}\int\limits_0^tu(\tau)d\tau dt,$$

separating variables I get,

\begin{align}
\hat{U}(w)&=\left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int\limits_0^tu(\tau)d\tau\frac{e^{-itw}}{-iw}\right)\right|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}+\frac{1}{iw}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-itw}u(t)dt\\
&=\left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int\limits_0^tu(\tau)d\tau\frac{e^{-itw}}{-iw}\right)\right|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}+\frac{\hat{u}(w)}{iw}.
\end{align}
I also know that the $\delta$ function can be expressed as

$$\delta(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-itw}dt,$$

but I don´t know how to use that, and so... I stop here

Answer (score 1):

Let 
\begin{equation}
f(t) \stackrel{a}= \int_{0}^t u(\tau) \mathrm d\tau \stackrel{b}=
\int_{-\infty}^t u(\tau) \mathrm d\tau  \stackrel{c}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u(\tau)u(t-\tau) \mathrm d\tau \stackrel{d}=u(t)*u(t)
\end{equation}

- $(a)$ Denote the integral you're seeking as $f(t)$.
- $(b)$ Since $u(t) = 0$ for $t<0$, then this does not change the integral
- $(c)$ Using $u(t-\tau) = 0$ for $t-\tau < 0$ and $1$ otherwise (i.e. $t > \tau$, which is the domain of integration.)
- $(d)$ Using the definition of convolution for continuous functions.

Using the convolution theorem and $U(w) = \frac{1}{iw }+\pi \delta( w)$, which is the Fourier transform of $u(t)$.
\begin{equation}
F(w )= U(w)U(w) = \frac{U(w)}{i w}+\pi U (w)\delta(w)
\end{equation}

Since $\delta(0)$ is the only non-zero point, then
\begin{equation}
F(\omega)=\frac{U(\omega)}{i\omega}+\pi U(0)\delta(\omega)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you do a more detailed explanation? Because I don´t understand your answer

Comment: which part don't you understand\

Comment: for example, in the second line, the second and the third equalities

Comment: No, I mean, $$\int_{0}^t u(\tau) \mathrm d\tau=
\int_{-\infty}^t u(\tau) \mathrm d\tau$$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^t u(\tau) \mathrm d\tau  = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} u(\tau)u(t-\tau) \mathrm d\tau$$

Comment: I have edited, please recheck

Comment: I saw, and thanks for that, but I still don´t understand equality $(c)$. For example, when $\tau=t/2$, in one side we have $u(t/2)$ which can be any real number, but on the other side we have $u(t/2)=u(t-t/2)=1$, which is as you defined $u(t-\tau)$ in equality (c)

Comment: where did the $2$ come from ? I did not write $2$

Comment: in the point of equality $(c)$: $u(t-\tau)=1$ when $\tau<t$

Comment: yes ? and what is the question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83347/discussion-between-fernando-and-ahmad-bazzi).